# How to combine multiple xml and prepare XSLT for the combined XML The above is the XSLT for one XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt

How to combine multiple XML and prepare XSLT for the combined XML?
I tried to combine multiple XML into one and tried to prepare XSLT transformation for that one. The above is the XSLT for one XML. Need to prepare XSLT for the combined XML.

```
XML-1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
  </cd>
</catalog>
XML-2
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque-1</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan-1</artist>
  </cd>
</catalog>

XSLT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">Details</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">XML-1</th>
    </tr>
 <tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
         ​  <td>Title</td>
     ​      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
    </xsl:for-each>
</tr>

​<tr>
   ​ <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
            <td>Artist</td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </xsl:for-each>
</tr>  

</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

The above is the XSLT for one XML. Need to prepare XSLT for the combined XML

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8ce7.jpg
```

Comment: Show us small but representative samples of two XML inputs, XSLT you have for a single file, together with the output you want for the two samples. Also explain which XSLT version and/or XSLT processor you use.

Comment: @MartinHonnen XML-1
 <directors>
      <director>
          <name>Steven</name>
          <age>60</age>
      </director>
 </directors>
XML-2
 <directors>
      <director>
          <name>Mathew</name>
          <age>55</age>
      </director>
 </directors>

XSLT I need is the table format with borders
Columns 2-Director and age

Directors  Age 
Steven     60
Mathew     55

Comment: @MartinHonnen i am using this link for xslt transformation https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog

Comment: @MartinHonnen <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"

Comment: Please edit your question to show any code samples in the question in a well-formatted way.

Comment: *"I tried to combine multiple XML into one and tried to prepare XSLT transformation for that one."*  Post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Kindly check the question now

Comment: Where is the "XSLT you have for a single file"? Or don't you even have that? It is not clear whether you are struggling to process more than one input document or whether the whole transformation, even for a single document, is not clear to you.

Comment: ~~~XML
XML-1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
  </cd>
</catalog>

XML-2
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Jack</title>
    <artist>Rose</artist>
  </cd>
</catalog>

Comment: @MartinHonnen  have attached 2 XMLS and XSLT for one XML in the question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Change `<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">` to e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd | document('XML-2.xml')/catalog/cd">`, to process the second document as well.

Comment: How can i combine multiple xml?

Comment: As shown, by using the `document` function to load secondary input documents.